# MySQL 1292 Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2020-09-11T08:32-50Z'

Tags: mysql, date, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1292

I need your help. I am trying to transform a text field (containing: 2020-09-11T08:32:50Z) into a date field. I have tried with TIMESTAMP statement and I get the warning: 1292 Truncated incorrect datetime value.
I have also tried with STR_TO_DATE statement and I get another warning: 1411 Incorrect datetime value.
I have entered SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES' to avoid some configuration error, but the error remains.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL understands the format up to the 'Z'. If you remove the 'Z' it will work fine.

Demo:

```
mysql> select date('2020-09-11T08:32:50Z');
+------------------------------+
| date('2020-09-11T08:32:50Z') |
+------------------------------+
| 2020-09-11                   |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                    |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2020-09-11T08:32:50Z' |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select date('2020-09-11T08:32:50');
+-----------------------------+
| date('2020-09-11T08:32:50') |
+-----------------------------+
| 2020-09-11                  |
+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

No warning is returned if the 'Z' is removed.

Comment: Yes, by removing Z, I was able to fix it. Thank you very much! I wanted to solve it without having to remove any data, but there was no way. Thanks!